# how does this python "for" compound statement work?

Tags: python

I saw the following solution for [a problem on leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/n-ary-tree-level-order-traversal/):

```
class Solution:
    def levelOrder(self, root):
        """
        :type root: Node
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """

        if root is None:
            return []

        q, res = [root], []
        q1 = []
        while q:
            res.append([node.val for node in q])
            q = [child for node in q for child in node.children]

        return res
```

How does `[child for node in q for child in node.children]` work? What does child mean when you place it before the for loop statement?

Comment: Have a look at list comprehension in Python.

Comment: i already looked at that..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a nested list comprehension.

```
q = [child for node in q for child in node.children]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
tmp = []
for node in q:
    for child in node.children:
        tmp.append(child)
q = tmp
```